# generic remote process accelerator

Tags: cluster, grid

is there a solution to accelerate a local process using remote PC CPUs (and/or GPU)?

My ideal solution should:

- **work without the need to rewrite the app to use a specific library**;
- work on heterogeneous OSes and archs (using dynamic recompilation if necessary);
- support service fail-over: if some network nodes go down, execution can still proceed on the remaining nodes (or even just locally if the main node became isolated).

use case:
 PC1 is less powerful than PC2, but i still like to run some CPU-hungry app on it and use its local resources during execution (the file system, USB periperals, etc.).
 So, instead of delegating the process execution completely (like in VNC), i'd like to delegate only a part of it dynamically at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

`is there a solution to accelerate a local process using remote PC CPUs (and/or GPU)?`

Yes, what you're describing is called a computer cluster.  But I gather you already knew that because you tagged the question as such.  So I will address your bullet points:

`work without the need to rewrite the app to use a specific library;`

No.  In the same way a multi-threaded application must be written to utilize a multi-core CPU, a distributed app must be written to distribute its workload among the nodes in a cluster.  Logistically, it's the same problem you have with people working together as a part of a team.  You have to come up with a plan, break it up into individual tasks, delegate those tasks to certain people, and then coordinate with those people to get the job done.  It has to be done that way because other people can't share your memory, hear your thoughts, or see the vision you have in your head.

`work on heterogeneous OSes and archs (using dynamic recompilation if necessary);`

This is possible either with a client written for each of the target platforms or with a common language like Java or Python.

`support service fail-over: if some network nodes go down execution can still proceed on the remaining nodes (or even just locally if the main node became isolated).`

A well-written distributed app does not need to worry about a node going down.  Compute tasks are broken up into segments by a "master node" and delegated to processing units from a list.  If a processing node goes down, those tasks never get done and remain in the list for other nodes to process.

---

No matter how you slice it, there is no magic bullet that will make a badass supercompute cluster for crunching Excel spreadsheets and running games.  Distributed applications must be specifically designed for that kind of task.  Remember that most applications cannot even make use of more than one processor core in the SAME machine let alone one in a computer somewhere out in the cloud.

Comment: I've found the Xgrid app is able to [run any program that can be run from the Mac OS X Terminal as a job](http://xgrid.plasticki.com/).
I'm not sure if it is exactly what i am looking for and i do not own a Mac to try it... Btw if i've got it right it shows the thing IS possible.

Comment: I've also found HTCondor can do that with its parallel universe, but it has more restrictions and it is harder to setup. Like Xgrid, it is limited to batch-like programs, not interactive/GUI programs or games which i was interested mostly...